# How to host React.js and Node.js app in windows IIS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, iis, host

i am trying to upload react.js app on cloud which have windows os installed . How can i upload and start my react app Using windows IIS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to install the node on the windows:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

install IIS by following these steps:

- Open control panel
- select Programs and Features, click on the link Turn Windows features on or off.
- Click on the Internet Information Services checkbox and select iis required features.
- open the iis manager from the installed application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-85/installing-iis-85-on-windows-server-2012-r2

after installing node and iis open command prompt as administrator and enter to the react js application folder.

example:

my react js application is under the C:\windows\system32\

to go to that path use command:

```
cd C:\windows\system32\my-app
```

run react app using :

```
npm start
```

check that application is running properly or not.

then run the command:

```
npm run build
```

You can see the build folder in your application folder.

- now open iis manager.
- select server name from the connection pane.right-click on it and select add-website:
  [image]
- in add website windows enter details like:
  site name
  folder path
  the port number, IP address, hostname, etc

note:
select the build folder when you add site path.

[image]

- Open site by click on the browse button from the action pane.

[image]

[image]

Comment: cool it worked . but now react routing not working only first page page is visible and if i tried to access other routes it shows error. can you please tell me why so .

Comment: From your post, I can see that your issue in the original post is solved now. I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer and create a new question in the new post for the SEO purpose .it is different from the parent question.
Thank you for understanding.

Comment: npm add react-router-dom see https://alex.domenici.net/archive/deploying-a-node-js-application-on-windows-iis-using-a-reverse-proxy

Comment: What if we are running Angular application inside Node.js. How we will host Node.js in that case so that it can run both ?